# How to assign the names according to their numbers?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm using 2010 excel version. 
Take a look at this example; You have these sheets:

```
Number  Name
1       Joseph
2       Mark
3       Cedric
4       Joe
5       Isabelle
```

and

```
Number  Name
3
4
1
2
5
```

I want a formula that assigns the names in the first sheet to the names in the second sheet so it looks like this:

```
Number  Name
3       Cedric
4       Joe
1       Joseph
2       Mark
5       Isabelle
```

PS: The names are in Arabic and the 1st sheet has duplicate values. Pardon me if I made a mistake, I don't much have any experience working with excel and I couldn't find what I'm looking for here. Thank you.

Comment: You can do this with [VLOOKUP()](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-vlookup-function).

Comment: @Bandersnatch And how would that work? I'm sorry I have no experience with excel formulas, if you could help me, I'd be glad.

Answer (score -1):

Check the Screen Shot:

[image]

*Write this Formula in Cell B2 of Sheet2 & fill down:*

```
 =VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$6,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: I couldn't achieve this as this was producing N/A, I achieved it via using node.js as I'm a node.js developer. Thank you anyway! Should I delete this thread?

Comment: I'm surprised,, Y U are unable to execute it successfully since I've loaded the screen shot for your convenience & see it's working !!

Comment: Rajesh I wasn't the one downvoting your answer, but as I said I'm new to excel and I tried it couple of times but your method didn't really work.